# PHP: Get OUTER diff between two arrays

Tags: php, arrays

How can I get outer difference between two array?

Reproduce:

```php
$a = array('11','22','33');
$b = array('22','44');
```

Expected result:

```php
array('11','33','44');
```

Currently I used below code for this, but I am looking for a simpler solution

```php
array_diff(array_merge($a, $b), array_intersect($a, $b));
```

Maybe PHP has a helper for this, but I am unaware of it

Comment: What does "simpler" mean?

Answer (score 1):

how about something like this?

```
array_merge(array_diff($a, $b), array_diff($b, $a));
```